# Стилистика русского языка. Обособленный оборот

Tags: стилистика

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где здесь допущена стилистическая ошибка.

**Недавние гастроли театра «Ла Скала»  в Москве, помимо их художественного значения, стали своего рода увертюрой к римским встречам на высшем уровне.**

1) Гастроли стали увертюрой; 2) Гастроли (какие?) недавние; 3) Гастроли (кого? чего?) театра «Ла Скала» (название образует со словом театр неразложимый оборот); 4) Гастроли (где?) в Москве;

Мне кажется, все правильно.

С большим уважением.текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти тонкие материи рассмотрены [здесь](http://k-l-f.ru/threads/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F.3650/). Привожу этот отрывок, на случай, если ссылка перестанет работать:

Открываю моего любимого Д.Э.Розенталя и читаю:

«…Приведем типичный случай использования приема схематизации и обнаружения нормативно-стилистической ошибки в построении предложения.

Недавние гастроли театра «Ла Скала» в Москве, помимо их художественного значения, стали своего рода увертюрой к римским встречам на высшем уровне.

Прибегнем к схематизации: 
1) Гастроли стали увертюрой; 
2) Гастроли (какие?) недавние; 
3) Гастроли (кого? чего?) театра «Ла Скала» (название образует со словом театр неразложимый оборот); 
4) Гастроли (где?) в Москве; 
5) Стали (помимо чего?) помимо значения.

Именно здесь и допущена грубая стилистическая ошибка, т.к. обособленный оборот 
«помимо их художественного значения» 
зависит в данном предложении от глагола-сказуемого стали, который управляет творительным падежом: кем-чем?, а слово значение зависит от другого глагола, с другим управлением: иметь (что?) значение.

Вариант правки:

Недавние гастроли театра «Ла Скала» в Москве не только имели большое художественное значение, но и стали своего рода увертюрой к римским встречам на высшем уровне.»